# Limit of a sum of cosines

Tags: limits, trigonometry, summation

I am trying to prove that

$$\lim_{N \to \infty} \frac 1 {2N} \sum_{k=1}^N [\cos((x-kL)\cdot q)+\cos((x+k L) \cdot q) ]=0$$

for every $x,L \in \mathbb R^+$ with $x \leq L$ and for every $q \neq \frac{2 n \pi}{L}$, $n \in \mathbb Z$.

The "hand-waving" motivation is that we will obtain a sum of oscillating functions which will interfere destructively everywhere (i.e. for every value of $q$) except in $q= \frac{2 n \pi}{L}$, $n \in \mathbb Z$, where we will obtain

$$\frac 1 {2N} \sum_{k=1}^N 2\cos(xq) =\cos(xq)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\cos (\alpha\pm\beta) = \cos \alpha \cos \beta \mp \sin \alpha \sin \beta.$$

Plugging this into your expression yields

$$\cos (xq)  \frac{1}{N} \sum_{k=1}^N  \cos (kL q).$$

Also,

$$\sin(\alpha\pm \beta) = \sin \alpha\cos\beta\pm \sin \beta \cos\alpha.$$

Therefore,

$$ 2\sin (\frac{\alpha}{2})  \cos (k \alpha)= \sin ((k+\frac 12)\alpha) -\sin((k - \frac 12 )\alpha).$$

This allows for a telescopic sum argument.

$$\frac{1}{N} \sum_{k=1}^N   \cos (kL q)= \frac{\sin ((N+\frac 12)Lq)- \sin (\frac 12 Lq)}{2N\sin (\frac{Lq}{2})}\underset{N\to \infty} {\to} 0$$